# Стиль программирования. Как вы оформляете шапки своих заголовочных и исходных файлов?

Tags: c++, лицензирование, css

Не то, чтобы проблема, но для меня этот вопрос чаще всего стоял остро. Итак, всякий исходник у меня следует такому шаблону:

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Source      : FileName.cpp
//  Created     : 09.07.2017
//  Modified    : Did not (if today)/Date
//  Author      : Alexander Bondarenko
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
#include "ALotOfHeaders.h"
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace name_of_space{ /* Code. */ }

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Подобное начало –  лицо программы. Но мне оно последнее время не особо нравится. Перемен хочется. Пример заголовочного файла, в целом, выглядит так:

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Header      : FileName.h
//  Created     : 09.07.2017
//  Modified    : Did not (if today)/Date
//  Author      : Alexander Bondarenko
//  Description : Simple Wrapper for something.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragra once // Because, I'm using MS VS only and don't like defines actually.
// Follow code is similar to previous.
```

Так вот, я много гуглил, да что-то не сильно гуглится мне подобная информация. Также, на глаз мне попадались исходники содержащие самые разные лицензии (в основном MIT и GNU). Что-то вроде:

```
// _Some_software_ is free software: you can redistribute it and modify
// it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
// the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
// (at your option) any later version.
```

Какой вы выбираете заголовок для своих src/h? Что мне посоветуете (не)делать? 
И объясните мне, как использовать лицензии или закрепить свое авторство, так сказать. Что-то вроде следующего?

```
// Copyright 2017, Alexander Bondarenko. All rights reserved.
```

Я считаю, каждый может дополнить этот вопрос чем-то своим, новым для меня и других пользователей. Возможно, кому-нибудь пригодится. Заранее спасибо.

---

Всем спасибо. Пересмотрел исходники многих проектов. Простите за нецелесообразный вопрос

```
// Copyright 2017, Alexander Bondarenko. All rights reserved.
```

Этого достаточно.

Comment: Не пишу шапки..

Comment: @andreymal, исчерпывающе.

Comment: Имя файла в заголовке этого файла -- пустая трата ресурсов.

Comment: А заголовок, который выбираю я, либо соответствует проекту, либо корпоративному стандарту.

Comment: Если работаете на фирме - то следуйте ее правилам. Если вольный стрелок - то как напишете, так и будет. Даже с лицензией - вряд ли кто на нее даже взглянет :) Так что пишите так, как удобнее **вам**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если копирайт важен (есть ограничения на использование кода), об этом надо написать в шапке:

```
// Copyright (c) 2017 MyCompany LLC. All rights reserved.
```

При этом если есть файл с лицензией (его может не быть если Вы никому не даете код), надо сделать на него ссылку.

```
// This code is under a BDSM-style license, see LICENSE.TXT
```

Если файл будут смотреть вне системы контроля версий, то можно добавить авторов, чтобы читающий знал у кому можно задавать вопросы.

```
// Author ivan@company.com
```

Хотя автора/время создания лучше смотреть в git log/git blame.
Либо авторов/владельцев можно поместить в отдельный файл OWNERS.txt .

Comment: Новый тренд -- использовать SPDX нотацию вместо текста лицензии. https://spdx.org/